# Getting a 404/405 error while making a post request from front end AJAX to a given route in node Js. The localhost URL doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, http-status-code-405

I want to load data from database as soon as page loads at front end, therefore I specified the route as '/' in GET. I am able to get the records in the console but my page doesn't load at http://127.0.0.1:3000. Here is a snap of the way I am creating server through node:
[image]

Yes I actually ran my server side through node app.js before creating this server

Moreover, even if it opens, and when I try to make a POST request to '/details' route, I get http 405 error. Here is a snap of my index.html where I am making an AJAX request:
[image]

In other ways, if I specify route as '/' in node Js and then make a request to '/', it inserts the record the way I want to.

I am quite new to AJAX and node Js. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Here is my entire server side code:

```
 const fetchOptions = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors'
};
var http=require("http");
var mysql=require("mysql");
var express=require('express');
var fs=require('fs');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var app=express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
console.log('Creating the http server');

var con= mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "budget_mgmt"
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err)
    {
      console.log('Error connecting to db');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection established');
});
var statement= "select * FROM budget_mgmt.item_description";
app.get('/',function(request,response)
{
    fs.readFile('index.html',function(err,data)
    {
        console.log("The home page: index.html");
    });
    con.query(statement,function(error,results, fields)
    {
         if(error) throw error;
         console.log(results);
         response.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });  //response.end(data);
});
app.post('/details',function(request,response)
{
    console.log(request.body);
  console.log(request.body.description);
    console.log(request.body.category);
  console.log(request.body.amount);
  console.log(request.body.date);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO item_description(description,category,amount,today) VALUES ('"
        +request.body.description+"','"+request.body.category+"',"+request.body.amount+","+"date_format(str_to_date('"+request.body.date+
        "','%m-%d-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d'));";
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("1 record inserted");
});
http.createServer(app).listen(3000,"127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Please include your code as a Code Sample (`{}`). [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Why You don't use `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch method?

Comment: As I see from images You run `http-server` that handles serving of static files and not made to serve Your serverside logic. Do it without http-server, just call:  `node app.js`

Comment: I actually called node app.js before running the server